# App was unable to start Android

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-manifest

Getting the error **"Unable To start myWeb*(my app's name)*"**
Can anybody Help me ? 
I am a newbie and just started coding android.

I ran this on eclipse and when the app is launched from ADT it gave error!!

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myweb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:name="testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThreeActivity"

     >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 
    />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myweb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@style/AppTheme"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
     >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:hint="Email Address or Phone Number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:hint="Password" 
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:minWidth="180dip"
        android:text="Log In" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/login1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/login1"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myweb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.login1);
        EditText emailBox   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        EditText passwordBox   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        final String emailId = emailBox.getText().toString();
        final String passwordId = passwordBox.getText().toString();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {             
           public void onClick(View v)  {               
            try {
                getUserLoggedIn(emailId,passwordId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }               
           }  
         });        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void getUserLoggedIn(String email,String password) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost  post = new HttpPost("localhost/testand.php");

        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `AsyncTask` for web page calling. And if you are using application in emulator then use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost`

Comment: what is AsyncTask ? and how to use it @Bills

Comment: It performs tasks asynchronously, off the UI thread, therefore not blocking that thread for snappy user experience. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example. Hope this link will be useful for you, please study

Comment: For your reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: WHere can i use it in my code? @Bills can u pleaes show ?

Comment: Can you post your entire logcat trace?

Comment: it was solved @Willis

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask like below and call it in `onCreate`

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<emailId, passwordId> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        getUserLoggedIn(emailId,passwordId);
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        Log.v("Webpage","Done");
     }
 }
```

and call in `onCreate`

```
            try {
               new DownloadFilesTask().execute(emailId,passwordId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solved It!![Solution Here]

*Actually this was solved...*.

In `activity_main.xml` i used `<button>` tag but in `.java` i used `ImageButton` to call it by id.

Though silly i solved it by using `Button` class instead of `ImageButton` in java file

Changed

`ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.login1);`

**to**

`Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login1);`

This fix was only specific to my code. So if anybody gets around error like this its time to recheck code rather than hanging around with Questions.

Comment: Please also use to see android log file to checkout errors and run-time exceptions, and it is better to attach your android catlog in question as well :)